# python site-packages pkg_resources.VersionConflicts

Tags: python, appium, pytest, python-appium

> File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2309, in load   File
>   "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line
>   2326, in require   File
>   "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line
>   810, in resolve pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (six 1.8.0
>   (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.8.0-py2.7.egg),
>   Requirement.parse('six>=1.9.0'))

Answer (score 0):

If anybody sees this error then run "python setup.py install --force" and "sudo easy_install six==1.10.0" or "sudo pip install --upgrade six"

And after this do a pycache clean up at the root dir level. This will fix your problems.